# Amazon RDS (MySQL) -> local dev / testing server Master-Master or Master-Slave + Example?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mysql, amazon-rds

I'm needing to replicate data from a primary Amazon RDS MySQL database to another local server  that acts as backup and a dev testing db, but I'm not sure which approach to take.  I know that there are advantages and disadvantages of running Master-Master and Master-Slave, but I'm not sure of all of the pros and cons.

I was hoping that someone could enumerate these as well as to actually offer an example of setting up the recommended scenario appropriately in terms of config files and the what ports need to communicate (I'm guessing 3306 will have to be forwarded), etc.

So as noted below, since an actual Amazon RDS to remote replication isn't an option, what about SymmetricDS?  I've heard some wonderful things about this and perhaps this is the right solution in this scenario.

**Still looking for some input in this scenario.  In particular, I think this can be done with SymetricDS, but could use some additional example input in this scenario.**

Answer (score 1):

Amazon RDS cannot currently be replicated off-RDS, as Amazon does not give you access to the binary logs.

Comment: Thanks, in that it appears that Amazon does not support that directly, what about using SymmetricDS or such to accomplish this?

Comment: You'd hace to investigate that. I have no experience with it and certainly couldn't vouch for reliability. You could always run your own MySQL on an EC2 instance and have full control, instead of RDS.